# AudioRecord not recording voice from MIC or VOICE_DOWNLINK while running in background service

Tags: android, service, android-service, audiorecord

I am working on a problem for recording audio in a voice call. I am using AudioRecord to get the recorded buffers. Now the problem is I want a background service that will always run and whenever a PHONE_STATE is OFFHOOK, it should record the buffers from user defined AudioSource (MIC or VOICE_DOWNLINK).

When I am recording voice in an activity button press, AudioRecord is recording buffers and saving it in PCM format which is playable in Audacity. It is recording file size of 100KB approx for 2 seconds of recording.

But when I am trying to start AudioRecord in my background service it is recording buffers which are not playable in Audacity. It is recording file size of 25MB approx for 2 seconds of recording that too not playable.

I searched extensively but could not find any solution yet. What am I doing wrong?

Below is my code

Here is my CallRecordingService.java

```
public class CallRecordingService extends Service {
    private final IBinder mBinder = new CallRecordingBinder();
    private AudioRecorder mAudioRecorder;
    private boolean mRecording = false;
    public ByteBuffer buffer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        IntentFilter callRecordingFilter = new IntentFilter();
        callRecordingFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
        registerReceiver(phoneStateListener, callRecordingFilter);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    BroadcastReceiver phoneStateListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, state + "- Recording Started ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mAudioRecorder = new AudioRecorder(getApplicationContext());
                mAudioRecorder.recordAudio(null);
                mRecording = true;
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state) && mRecording == true) {
                Toast.makeText(context, state + "- Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mAudioRecorder.stopRecording();
                mRecording = false;
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
                String fname = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                //Toast.makeText(context, state + " : " + fname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    public class CallRecordingBinder extends Binder {
        CallRecordingService getService() {
            return CallRecordingService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

In AudioRecorder.java (custom class as wrapper over android AudioRecord.java). I am starting a thread inside recordAudio() method, to read the buffers and save it in a file as below method.

```
private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
        // Write the output audio in byte

        String filePath = "/sdcard/voice16K16bitmono.pcm";
        short sData[] = new short[BufferElements2Rec];

        FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (isRecording) {

            audioRecord.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
            System.out.println("Short writing to file" + sData.toString());
            try {
                // // writes the data to file from buffer
                // // stores the voice buffer
                byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);
                Log.i("Size", "bData Size : " + bData.length);
                os.write(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Message - Recording done.");


        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private byte[] short2byte(short[] sData) {
        int shortArrsize = sData.length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[shortArrsize * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < shortArrsize; i++) {
            bytes[i * 2] = (byte) (sData[i] & 0x00FF);
            bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (byte) (sData[i] >> 8);
            sData[i] = 0;
        }
        return bytes;

    }
```

And Here is my main activity class from which I am starting service.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CallRecordingService mService = null;
    private Button startRecordingService, stopRecordingService;
    private static MainActivity activityInstance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityInstance = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startRecordingService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartRecording);
        stopRecordingService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopRecording);

        startRecordingService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallRecordingService.class);
                bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                startService(intent);
            }
        });

        stopRecordingService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                unbindService(mConnection);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            CallRecordingService.CallRecordingBinder b = (CallRecordingService.CallRecordingBinder) service;
            mService = b.getService();
        }
    };

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return activityInstance;
    }
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testsmartcalling"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.example.testsmartcalling.CallRecordingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLTETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you trying to record phone call? Because if so, I suppose Phone application just locks MIC input, so you get nothing.

Comment: Yes I am recording Phone Call. I made changes in Android Framework code. Anyway the issue has been solved I will close it.

Answer (score -2):

I solved the issue finally. I had to make some framework changes in Android code to enable this feature. Due to legal issues some OEMs disable call recording feature.

Comment: What changes did you make? How did you enable the feature?

Comment: I don't remember exact changes but there were quite a few changes done in AudioFlinger. You can trace it from Audio Service to all the way down.